# Review my API Controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to javascript backend and I am currently learning to build a RESTful API using node.js, express.js, sequelize.js with MySQL as my database. I have successfully built a basic Tasks API as a test. I am looking for feedback on if I did this correctly as far as javascript best practices go within one controller. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Current Logic: User can own multiple tasks

Everything works fine. I am authenticating the users using JWT strategy in Passport.js. I am authenticating them at the router level and then I am double-checking their records in db through userid before they are allowed to make any updates or deletes to their own records. Anyways, here is the controller:

```
    'use strict';

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var config = require('../config'),
    db = require('../services/database'),
    Task = require('../models/task');

var TaskController = {};

// GET ALL Tasks
TaskController.get = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.user.id) {
        res.json({ message: 'You are not authorized.' });
    } else {
        db.sync().then(function () {
            return Task.findAll({ where: { userid: req.user.id } }).then(function (result) {
                res.status(202).json(result);
            });
        });
    }
}

// POST ONE Task
TaskController.post = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.task) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to post.' });
    } else {
        db.sync().then(function () {
            var newTask = {
                userid: req.user.id,
                task: req.body.task
            };

            return Task.create(newTask).then(function () {
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Task Created!' });
            });
        });
    }
}

// PUT ONE Task
TaskController.put = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.task) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to update.' });
    } else {
        db.sync().then(function () {
            // Find task by task id and user id
            Task.find({ where: { id: req.params.id, userid: req.user.id } })
                .then(function (task) {
                    // Check if record exists in db
                    if (task) {
                        task.update({
                            task: req.body.task
                        }).then(function () {
                            res.status(201).json({ message: 'Task updated.' });
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found.' });
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}

// DELETE ONE Task
TaskController.delete = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.params.id) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to delete.' });
    } else {
        db.sync().then(function () {
            Task.find({ where: { id: req.params.id, userid: req.user.id } })
                .then(function (task) {
                    if (task) {
                        task.destroy({ where: { id: req.params.id } })
                            .then(function () {
                                res.status(202).json({ message: 'Task deleted.' });
                            });
                    } else {
                        res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found.' });
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = TaskController;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review platform. Do not ask such questions here. There is a code review stack exchange you can find at the bottom of this page. You should delete this question and ask there.

Comment: How is this an off-topic question? I am asking experienced programmers to review my code and point out any mistakes that I may have made. If this is not the right platform to do this then please suggest some that you prefer. thanks

Comment: You are asking for feedback and best practices which are opinion. You are not asking about mistakes in your code which you said works. These are both off topic as outlined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **TaskController.js** looks good but I would suggest moving all the ORM logic (Sequelize) to a file called **TaskService.js**

Example -

In **TaskService.js** -

```
...

exports.delete = function() {
    db.sync().then(function () {
        Task.find({ where: { id: req.params.id, userid: req.user.id } })
            .then(function (task) {
                if (task) {
                    task.destroy({ where: { id: req.params.id } })
                        .then(function () {
                            res.status(202).json({ message: 'Task deleted.' });
                        });
                } else {
                    res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found.' });
                }
            });
    });
}
```

then in **TaskController.js** -

```
...

const TaskService = require('./TaskService);

...

TaskController.delete = function(req, res) {
    if (!req.params.id) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to delete.' });
    } else {
        TaskService.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...

    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd like to call out as far as Javascript best practices would be nested promises, which is a bit of an anti-pattern. You lose the power of promise chains when you nest them, in effect creating nested callbacks. Things will start getting weird once you start trying to use `.catch()` blocks for error handling. A quick refactor with catch blocks might look like this, even though this is still messy because of the conditional based on the whether or not the task exists in the DB:

```
// PUT ONE Task
TaskController.put = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.task) {
    res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to update.' });
  } else {
    db.sync()
      .then(function () {
        // Find task by task id and user id
        // NOTE: we return the promise here so that we can chain it
        // to the main promise chain started by `db.sync()`
        return Task.find({ where: { id: req.params.id, userid: req.user.id } });
      })
      .then(function (task) {
        // Check if record exists in db
        if (task) {
          task.update({ task: req.body.task })
          .then(function () {
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'Task updated.' });
          })
          .catch(function (updateError) {
            // do something with your update error
            // catches an error thrown by `task.update()`
          });
        } else {
          res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found.' });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (promiseChainError) {
        // do something with your promiseChainError
        // this catch block catches an error thrown by 
        // `db.sync()` and `Task.find()`
      });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're more comfortable with synchronous style code and have the option of updating your node version to v7+, this is what your functions might look like using async/await:

```
// PUT ONE Task
TaskController.put = async function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.task) {
    res.json({ message: 'Please provide a task to update.' });
  } else {
    try {
      await db.sync();
      const task = await Task.find({ where: { id: req.params.id, userid: req.user.id } });

      // Check if record exists in db
      if (task) {
        await task.update({ task: req.body.task });
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Task updated.' });
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found.' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // do some something with your error
      // catches all errors thrown by anything in the try block
    }
  }
}
```

There's plenty of resources out there about promise chains and handling async methods. Check this one out in particular: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...

    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer